# Pass a variable from controllers

Tags: angularjs

I am programing in Angularjs, and have have a page that is divided into 3 teplates which one has an html file and js file.
The js file of which template is characterized for having the controller of the html of that template. 
At the end i want to pass a variable from a certain controller to another how can i do that once they are in different controllers. Thanks

Mr.Avraam Mavridis, here is some code:

Basically down here is the controller that i want to get the value of the parameter (clientPosition) to pass it to another controller:

```
crm.controller("clientsModule", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http {  
$scope.changeTemplate = function (index, clientPosition) {
   $scope.panelTemplate = index;
   $scope.clientPosition = clientPosition;
    };
}]);
```

Comment: can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways you can achieve this. The easiest way to do this is using a broadcast and watch. You basically set the value in the controller you want to and create a broadcast event for it. In the controller that you would like to access the value, you put a watch and listen to any updates for the value.

> The above way is also the dirtiest way to achieve what you want

A more elegant solution would involve create a model binding on the view and accessing those properties via logical progression on the controller you want to access that value in. You essentially create an angular service for your models and then access those services in the controllers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarify and provide me with two good ways to solve my issue.